# chrome extension gmail login

Tags: email, authentication, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I just started developing chrome extension. I have success in FB, LinkedIn etc..

**Issue:** 
Gmail has 2 separate input page verification (email and password) unlike FB or LinkedIn.

```
var email="myEmail";
var pass = "myPassword";

$('#email').val(email);
$('#pass').val(pass);

$('#login_form').submit();
```

.

If I'm going to do the same (like I've done in FB), **ONLY the Email script will run** but the password script won't continue to run.

My searches says **to pass** the data to background script but unfortunately **Im stuck to this**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({email: email, pass: pass, web: website}, function (response) {
            //alert("msg received. ");                
        });
```

***Should I continue? Am I on the right path?***

What are other solution if there is?
.

*Sorry, if its too newbie, Im just trying to explore how to code extensions.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could continue but it's not easy as FB or LinkedIn, and you know the reason.
The issue was caused because when we submit username into Google login page, it already turned into another page which not included your scripts anymore.

There was a way to work around is that you could create another content script to type in the password. It's the same as when you type in your username, if the page is the input password page then enter the password which stored some where on your browser by Chrome API. I considered this as a tech debt so consider before using this.

If you just want to learn to write your own extension, I would recommend that you could come up with an idea and then research related API, gather as most information as possible and start to implement it, you will see that your learning progress faster than just trying around for some demo or something